# Bash to Python: flatten directory tree

Tags: python, bash

On Unix-like systems I use this script, which I'd like some help on porting to Python for execution on Windows hosts:

---

```
#!/bin/bash

SENTINEL_FILENAME='__sentinel__'
SENTINEL_MD5_CHECKSUM=''
SENTINEL_SHA_CHECKSUM=''

function is_directory_to_be_flattened() {

  local -r directory_to_consider="$1"
  local -r sentinel_filepath="${directory_to_consider}/${SENTINEL_FILENAME}"

  if [ ! -f "${sentinel_filepath}" ]; then
    return 1
  fi

  if [[
      "$(
         md5 "${sentinel_filepath}" \
           | awk '{ print $NF }' 2> /dev/null
       )" \
        == "${SENTINEL_MD5_CHECKSUM}"
    && \
      "$(
         shasum -a 512 "${sentinel_filepath}" \
           | awk '{ print $1 }' 2> /dev/null
       )" \
        == "${SENTINEL_SHA_CHECKSUM}"
  ]]; then
    return 0
  else
    return 1
  fi
}

function conditionally_flatten() {

  local -r directory_to_flatten="$1"
  local -r flatten_into_directory="$2"

  if is_directory_to_be_flattened "${directory_to_flatten}"; then

    if [ ! -d "${flatten_into_directory}" ]; then
      mkdir -v "${flatten_into_directory}"
    fi

    for file_to_move in $(find ${directory_to_flatten} -type f -maxdepth 1); do
      mv \
        -v \
        -n \
        "${file_to_move}" \
        "${flatten_into_directory}"
    done
  fi
}

function flatten_directory() {

  local -r directory_to_flatten="$1"
  local -r descend_depth="$2"

  local -r flattened_directory="${directory_to_flatten}/__flattened__"

  if [ ! -d "${directory_to_flatten}" ]; then
    printf "The argument '%s' does not seem to be a directory.\n" \
      "${directory_to_flatten}" \
      >&2
    return
  fi

  find "${directory_to_flatten}" \
    -type d \
    -maxdepth "${descend_depth}" \
  | \
    while read directory_path; do
      conditionally_flatten \
        "${directory_path}" \
        "${flattened_directory}"
    done
}

n_arguments="$#"

if [ "${n_arguments}" -eq 1 ]; then
  flatten_directory "$1" '1' # maybe use a constant, not a "magic #" here?
else
  echo usage: "$0" /path/to/directory/to/flatten
fi

unset is_directory_to_be_flattened
unset conditionally_flatten
unset flatten_directory
```

---

How would you port this to Win Python? I am a beginner in both Python and Bash scripting..

Feel free to upgrade my implementation as you port it if you find it lacking in any way too, with a justification please. This is not "Code Review" but a "thumbs up/thumbs down" on my effort in Bash would give me a sense of whether I am improving or I should change the way I study altogether...

---

Here we go, my attempt in Python: (criticise it *hard* if need be, it's the only way for me to learn!)

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import sys
import os
import shutil

SENTINEL_FILENAME=''
SENTINEL_MD5_CHECKSUM=''
SENTINEL_SHA_CHECKSUM=''

DEFAULT_DEPTH = 1
FLATTED_DIRECTORY_NAME = '__flattened__'

def is_directory_to_be_flattened(directory_to_consider):
  sentinel_location = os.path.join(directory_to_consider, SENTINEL_FILENAME)
  if not os.path.isfile(sentinel_location):
    return False
  import hashlib
  with open(sentinel_location) as sentinel_file:
    file_contents = sentinel_file.read()
    return (hashlib.md5(file_contents).hexdigest() == SENTINEL_MD5_CHECKSUM
      and hashlib.sha512(file_contents).hexdigest() == SENTINEL_SHA_CHECKSUM)

def flatten(directory, depth, to_directory, do_files_here):
  if depth < 0:
    return
  contained_filenames = [f for f in os.listdir(directory)]
  if do_files_here:
    for filename in contained_filenames:
      if filename == SENTINEL_FILENAME:
        continue
      filepath = os.path.join(directory, filename)
      if not os.path.isfile(filepath):
        continue
      file_to = os.path.join(to_directory, filename)
      if not os.path.isdir(to_directory):
        os.makedirs(to_directory)
      if not os.path.isfile(file_to):
        print "Moving: '{}' -> '{}'".format(filepath, file_to)
        shutil.move(filepath, file_to)
      else:
    sys.stderr.write('Error: {} exists already.\n'.format(file_to))
  next_depth = depth - 1
  for subdirectory in (d for d in contained_filenames if os.path.isdir(d)):
    if is_directory_to_be_flattened(subdirectory):
      flatten(subdirectory, next_depth, to_directory, True)

def flatten_directory(to_flatten, depth):
  to_directory = os.path.join(to_flatten, FLATTED_DIRECTORY_NAME)
  if not os.path.isdir(to_flatten):
    sys.stderr.write(
      'The argument {} does not seem to be a directory.\n'.format(
      to_flatten))
    return
  flatten(to_flatten, depth, to_directory, False)

def main():
  if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    flatten_directory(sys.argv[1], DEFAULT_DEPTH)
  else:
    print 'usage: {} /path/to/directory/to/flatten'.format(sys.argv[0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

---

Although it's obvious from the code, the intent is:

- Start at a given directory
- Descend up to a certain depth
- Consider subdirectories and move all files therein if and only if:

  - The directory contains a "sentinel file" with a given filename
  - The sentinel file is *actually* a sentinel file, not just a file renamed to the same name
- Collate files in a `__flattened__` directory under the directory in which the search started

Comment: The main purpose on S.O. is not to have other people do the work for you. You have to try some thing, and then come up with your doubts.

Comment: **No problem**, _let me show my own port then_! Give me a few minutes to find it...

Comment: Here we go, posted. I had to update VirtualBox and start-up Windows...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most file dealing functions in Python are in the module "os" - therein you will find
os.rename (for renaming or moving a directoruy entry), os.listdir - which gives you a listing of filenames in the directory, passed as first arg, os.walk - to recursively walk through a directory structure, os.path.walk, to do the same, but with a callback, os.path.exists, os.path.isdir, os.mkdir, are others that might be  handy.

For a "quick and dirty" translation you might also cehck "os.system". which allows you to execute a shell command just like it was typed in the shell, and os.popen - which allows access to stdin and stdout of said process. A more carefull translation, tough, would require using anothe module: "subprocess" which can give one full control of a shell command  executed as  sub process (although if you need `find`, for example, it won't be available on windows)

Other moduless of interest are `sys` (sys.argv are the arguments passed to the script) and `shutil` (with things like copy, rmtree and such)

Your script does some error checking, and it is trivial, given the above funcion names in "os" and basic Python to add them - but a short "just do it" script in Python could be just:

```
import os, sys

dir_to_flatten = sys.argv[1]

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dir_to_flatten):
    for filename in filenames:
        try:
            os.rename(os.path.join(dirpath, filename), os.path.join(dir_to_flatten, filename))
        except OSError:
            print ("Could not move %s " % os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
```

Comment: @Talvalin: indeed. Fixed. Thanks.